# Unable to call service from tomcat with SSL

Tags: grails, tomcat7

I am using tomcat7. I configured TOMCAT to enable SSL in server.xml file like this,

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
port="443" keystoreFile="C:\Users\Administrator\.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I were unable to call services from app running in tomcat and I also tried calling via POSTMAN and it showed like this,

[image]

Did I do something wrong? or do I have to do something more ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Port. You set up port `443` for *SSL*, but in request you are using `80`(default).